# C# Hiding a process (Process doesn't hide)

Tags: c#, cookies, process, hide

I'm trying to hide a process before and even after I start it, but it doesn't seem to work at all. Can anyone explain this?

[image: The process showing up anyways]

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo StartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("rundll32.exe", "InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 2");
StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
Process.Start(StartInfo);
StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```

Comment: I'm think that this is a dialog, and not the main process window.

Comment: Any idea if it's possible to hide that then? But I don't think it's a dialog, more like a process window maybe. And I guess Microsoft made it just to troll.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to hide the process from not showing in Task Manager for example, then you would need to do one of the following:

- API Hooking. (Ring-3)
- Altering the `EPROCESS` structure of the targeted process. (Ring-0)

I hope I understood your question correctly, cause your question and posted snippet does not match really.